# Por qué imprime null a la par de la palabra de un String[]?

Tags: java, java-ee

```
String texto="palabra1 palabra2 palabra3 palabra4";
String espacio=" ";

for(int i=0;i<texto.length();i++){
      if(texto.charAt(i)==espacio.charAt(0)){
         contador++;
      }
}

String[] salida = new String[contador+1];

for (int x=0;x<texto.length();x++) {
   if(texto.charAt(x)!=espacio.charAt(0)){
       salida[index]+=texto.charAt(x);
    }else{
       index ++;
         }
  } 

for(int j=0;j<salida.length;j++){
    System.out.println("palabra:"+j+" ---->"+ salida[j]);
}
```

`
en consola muestra:

1. palabra: 0 ----> nullpalabra1 ;
2. palabra: 1 ----> nullpalabra2 ;
3. palabra: 2 ----> nullpalabra3 ;
4. palabra: 3 ----> nullpalabra4 ;
   `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razòn por la cual se imprime null es que al inicializar tu array inicialmente tienes valores null:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y posteriormente concatenas los valores de cada caracter, por esta razòn tienes al inicio el valor "null".

```
 salida[index] += texto.charAt(x);
```

Una opciòn es inicializar los valores de tu array con una cadena vacia por ejemplo:

```
String[] salida =  {"","","",""};
```

de esta forma al iniciar tendràs valores vacios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta forma obtendràs la salida:

```
palabra:0 ---->palabra1
palabra:1 ---->palabra2
palabra:2 ---->palabra3
palabra:3 ---->palabra4
```

---

Veo que editaste tu pregunta, incluso para inicializar con una cadena vacia puedes usar tambièn:

```
  String[] salida = new String[contador+1];     
  Arrays.fill(salida, "");
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias por la información! con eso pude solucionar el problema

Comment: Hola @Bennacer eso es excelente, saludos!